# Missing zxJDBC connector in sqlalchemy (With DB2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, db2

Facing issue with a `sqlalchemy` + `db2`(remote server) application.

Dependency installed:

- SQLAlchemy==1.4.21
- ibm-db==3.0.4
- ibm-db-sa==0.3.6
- python version = 3.8

Here is the connection snippet:

```
self.__engine = create_engine(f'ibm_db_sa://{DB2_USER}:{DB2_PASSWD}@{DB2_INSTANCE}/{DB2_DB}')
```

Seeing below issue:

```
File "/db-query-service/query_executor/db_reader/db2_reader_with_query.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.__engine = create_engine(f'ibm_db_sa://{DB2_USER}:{DB2_PASSWD}@{DB2_INSTANCE}/{DB2_DB}')
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 522, in create_engine
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 653, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 337, in load
    return impl.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ibm_db_sa/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import ibm_db, pyodbc, base, zxjdbc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ibm_db_sa/zxjdbc.py", line 32, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.connectors.zxJDBC import ZxJDBCConnector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy.connectors.zxJDBC'
```

Questions:

- Is there any dependency missing or mismatch in versions?
- Is there any issue with `sqlalchemy` installation? - I removed and reinstalled it to rule that out.
- Able to work with Mysql remote db.
- `zxjdbc` is specific to `jython` i found, will `db2`+ `Sqlalchemy` work with jython implementations.?
- If `db2`+ `Sqlalchemy` work with cpython, what's the fix for the issue?

Reference Doc:

- Here is the [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0060891.html)

Comment: Uninstall sqlalchemy 1.4x.  Then install sqlalchemy==1.3.24 .

Comment: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/issues/98

Comment: Thanks a lot, issue is resolved. I hope IBM updates this issue in their docs.  You may update the answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporarily, you need to uninstall the sqlalchemy 1.4.x  and as a workaround, then install the current sqlalchemy 1.3.x release . At today's date this is sqlalchemy 1.3.24 which should resolve the issue.

I expect this problem will eventually get resolved.

Link to issue is [here](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/issues/98)